# UITableViewCell & UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make an UITableView with prototype cells. Now i'm getting into a problem. I use 3 kind of different prototype cells, and in 2 of them there is a UITextField.

I'm doing it on this way, i have subclassed the UITableViewCell 2 times, for the Outlets of my UITextFields for getting the information out of the Fields.

Am i'm doing it on the right way? Or do i need to redo my approach?

**Here is my code [UPDATE]:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:{
            CellIdentifier = @"nameCell";
            naamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[naamCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

            [cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

            return cell;
            break;
        }

        default:{
            if(indexPath.row == [[_diceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]count]){
                CellIdentifier = @"addCell";

            }else{
                CellIdentifier = @"optionCell";
                optionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[optionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                }
                [[cell optionCell] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[_diceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] ;
                [cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

                return cell;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

So here is a picture of what is happening. So i have 2 sections. Added like 2 things in my textfields there. Delete one from section 2. The content from the UITextField goes to section 3 and doesn't get deleted:
[image: Error]

EDIT 2:
I've updated the code. So people can dynamically edit the UITextField. I'm getting there i think, tested it with presented NSStrings in my Array, then Cell.textfield.text = text from array from index of section.

Now i need to find a way that the user can add text on it's own, and when pressing or changing textfield the text get's saved to my array and then do [Table ReloadData]; Or is this not the right way to do it?

Comment: When you say you have subclassed your cells, did you create a separate nib file for each one? Because if that is the case, you might need to register the nibs, possibly at the viewDidLoad method. Also, do the prototype cells each has a different identifier in the storyboard?

Comment: I have setup the prototype cells in my Storyboard, gave it an custom class, and gave it different identifiers.

Comment: An issue is not apparent.   Is something not working the way you expect?  What's the problem that you mention?

Comment: It's not working quite well. When i add 2 value's to my section 2. and delete them again, add rows to section 3, they will reappear there.

Comment: is it static values or dynamic values that you are displayed in tableViewCell.

Comment: @Kets do you want to change this cells dynamically?

Comment: Yeah i want to, the user needs to enter stuff. I'll edit my post for a new update. I think i'm getting there. But still need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have finally gotten it!

Needed to implement this:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UIView* v = textField;

    do {
        v = v.superview;
    } while (![v isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]);
    optionCell* cell = (optionCell*)v;

    NSIndexPath* ip = [self._tabel indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (![textField.text isEqual:[[_diceArray objectAtIndex:ip.section] objectAtIndex:ip.row]]) {
        [[_diceArray objectAtIndex:ip.section] setObject:textField.text atIndex:ip.row];
    }
}
```